# Question about the Hessian matrix and its eigenvalues

Tags: analysis

Let $\Omega$ a bounded and connected domain in $R^n$ and $a_{ij} \in C(\Omega)$, $i,j=1,...,n$ such that

$$\lambda |\theta|^2 \leq a_{ij}(x)\theta_i \theta_j \leq \gamma |\theta|^2, i,j=1,...,n$$

for any $x \in \Omega$ and for any $\alpha = (\theta_1,...,\theta_n) \in R^n$ for some positive constants $\lambda $ and $\gamma$.

I am reading a book and the book says:

For any function $\varphi $that is $C^2$ at $x_0 \in \Omega$ we have the following equivalence

$\sum_{i,j=1}^{n} a_{ij}(x_0)D_{ij}\varphi(x_0) \leq 0 <=> \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_k e_k \leq 0$
with $\lambda \leq \alpha_k \leq \gamma$ and $e_k = e_k(D^2 \varphi(x_0))$

where $e_1,...,e_n$ are the eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix $D^2 \varphi(x_0)$.

Someone could help me to prove this equivalence? Probably it is a simple thing , but I am not seeing the trick...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the $\{\alpha_k\}$ the eigenvalues?  Also, the inequality in the first line; is that for every $i$ and $j$ or summed over all $i$ and $j$?

Comment: the book does not say if is the eigenvalues.  the first inequality holds foar all i,j . i will fix the last thing. thanks